# Android - Converting Bitmap to Drawable from SDCard

Tags: android, bitmap, android-drawable

Hey having something odd showing up when I convert a Bitmap from SDCard to a Drawable with regards to resizing:

```
String sdDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
String filename = "test.png"; //420px X 420px
Drawable tmpDraw;
Bitmap tmpBit = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(sdDir+filename);

Log.e("BAH","Bitmap height:"+tmpBit.getHeight()); //420

tmpDraw = (Drawable) new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),tmpBit);
int height = tmpDraw.getMinimumHeight();

Log.e("BAH","Drawable height:"+height); //420
```

I'm assuming that I need a point of reference to scale from? If a file is read from SDCard is it classed as MDPI and this is why it gets rescaled? I'm currently using a Nexus 7 to test which is TVDPI. I would like the scaling to occur as if the Bitmap is in HDPI.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Think I've cracked it:

```
String sdDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
String filename = "test.png"; //420px X 420px
Drawable tmpDraw;

BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
DisplayMetrics metrics = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
options.inDensity = 240; //Being DPI for HDPI
options.inTargetDensity=metrics.densityDpi; //Being current DPI
//inDensity/inTargetDensity are a ratio

Bitmap tmpBit = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(sdDir+filename,options);

Log.e("BAH","Bitmap height:"+tmpBit.getHeight()); //373 Correct for TVDPI

tmpDraw = (Drawable) new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),tmpBit);
int height = tmpDraw.getMinimumHeight();

Log.e("BAH","Drawable height:"+height); //373 Correct for TVDPI
```

Is this an acceptable way to do it?

Comment: what do you want exactly? do you want to prevent scaling and have the height 420 instead of 315 ?

Comment: I would like the scaling to occur as if the Bitmap on the SDCard is  in HDPI. Either at the Bitmap or Drawable level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you're supposed to pass a `Resources` to the `BitmapDrawable` constructor so it doesn't mess this up.

Comment: Semi answered. tmpDraw = (Drawable) new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),tmpBit); produces no rescaling from Bitmap to Drawable. How do I get the initial Bitmap to scale assuming SDCard is in HDPI format?

Comment: Will give you the answered tick for this because you did point out the problem with scaling between Bitmap and Drawable. Thank you!